# FormData in React is correct, but Redux says undefined (edited)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern, cloudinary

I want to update data from react by using FormData. When I console.log() Formdata, every key value pair is correct. After dispatch, it graps the updateMainNews and the redux-devtools are telling me: pending, rejected and I get the alert:

> localhost:3000 includes undefined.

Because of the answers I get here, I have edited my code, and the error above is gone away. But the update not really works. First I have endless pending and the console throws the error:

> state.mainnews.push is not a function

But when I refresh my site, the article is updated. And I have an endless running message in the console:

> Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for .

That is my Formdata, in which is everything correct:

```
  const onSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const mainnewsData = new FormData();
    mainnewsData.append("ressort", data.ressort);
    mainnewsData.append("theme", data.theme);
    mainnewsData.append("title", data.title);
    mainnewsData.append("content", data.content);
    mainnewsData.append("img", fileData);
   for(let value of mainnewsData){
        console.log(value);
   }
   console.log(id);
   const updateData = {id: id, mainnewsData: mainnewsData}
    dispatch(updateMainNews(updateData));

    return ()=>{
        dispatch(reset());
    }
}
```

Then it goes to my Slice:

```
export const updateMainNews = createAsyncThunk("mainNews/update", async (updateData, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.accessToken;
        return await mainnewsService.updateMainNews(updateData, token);
    } catch(error){
        const message = (error.response 
            && error.response.data 
            && error.response.data.message) 
            || error.message 
            || error.toString();
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})
```

My extraReducer:

```
 .addCase(updateMainNews.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
                state.isLoading = false;
                state.isSuccess = true;
                state.mainnews.push(action.payload);
            })
```

My redux-service:

```
const updateMainNews = async (updateData, token)=>{
    const config = {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
            token: `Bearer ${token}`}
    }
    const response = await axios.put(API_URL + updateData.id, updateData.mainnewsData, config);
    return response.data;
}
```

The backend:

```
router.put("/:id", upload.single("img"), verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        let updatedMainNews = await MainNews.findById(req.params.id);
        console.log(updatedMainNews);
        //destroy
        await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(updatedMainNews.cloudinary_id);
        //upload
        let result;
        if(req.file){
        result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
            upload_preset: "Mern_redux-practice",
            resource_type: "auto",
        })
        }
        const updatedData = {
            ressort: req.body.ressort || updatedMainNews.ressort,
            theme: req.body.theme || updatedMainNews.theme,
            title: req.body.title || updatedMainNews.title,
            content: req.body.content || updatedMainNews.content,
            cloudinary_id: result.public_id || updatedMainNews.cloudinary_id,
            img: result.secure_url || updatedMainNews.img,
        }
        updatedMainNews = await MainNews.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, updatedData, {
            new:true,
        })

        res.status(200).json(updatedMainNews);
    } catch(error){
        res.status(404)
        throw new Error("Not found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please read https://github.com/axios/axios#using-multipartform-data-format as you should not have to specify the form data header manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working with form data you have to send the content-type as well.

When you are passing variables to createAsyncThunk or reducer action you have to pass it as one argument. The way you can do it is by passing an object instead.

```
dispatch(updateMainNews({id, mainnewsData}))
```

Then you need to use deconstruct the variables.

```
export const updateMainNews = createAsyncThunk("mainNews/update", async ({id, mainnewsData}, thunkAPI)=>{
try{
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.accessToken;
    return await mainnewsService.updateMainNews(id, mainnewsData, token);
} catch(error){
    const message = (error.response 
        && error.response.data 
        && error.response.data.message) 
        || error.message 
        || error.toString();
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
}
```

})

Hope this works out for you.

Comment: Hello newbieDev, I did it like this, and it updated, but I get an endless loop.

Comment: Setting the object in an variable, has solved a part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Where do you get an endless loop?

Comment: It works now, so don't mind. I found out, the issue was in the frontend. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send a form data, but you are sending a request with content-type json.

```
'Content-Type':'application/json',
```

When sending form data, your request content-type should be:

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

Comment: Hello Briuor, thank you for your answer, I have changed it, like you said. But I have the same result.

Comment: Can you console log and show the content of API_URL, console.log(API_URL + mainNewsId), Maybe your API_URL is wrong, because of the error localhost:3000 includes undefined

Comment: The path is correct,  I made it like newbieDev said it in his answer it, and it has updated, but at the same time, I had an endless loop with a totally shotdown of my computer.

Comment: I have edited my code. so a part of the problem has gone.